# Sending email using code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1868

Backtrace:

File: /home/abc/public_html/isol/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 261
Function: send

File: /home/abc/public_html/isol/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

When ever I send email I get this error  .
My code is below

```html
$config = Array('mailtype' => 'html');
$this->load->library('email',$config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 
$this->email->from(from_email,site_title); 
$this->email->to('ammarkhan94x@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject(site_title.' - Account Registration'); 
$this->email->message('<p><b>Dear '.$fname.' '.$lname.',</b></p>'.
'<p>Thank You for registration on '.site_title.', Your account is created successfully please login & update your account details.</p>');  
$result = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Php version, ci version?

Comment: php version is 7.2 CI 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

In Application/config/email.php

```
<?php

$config['email_conf'] = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => '-your smtp port-',
    'smtp_port' => -your smtp port-,
    'smtp_user' => '-your email--',
    'smtp_pass' => '-your smtp pass',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

In your controller

```
     private function sendMail($mailBody) {
        //en-tête de mail
        $filename = 'assets/images/logo.png';
        //loader les fichiers de configuration
        $this->config->load('email');
        $conf = $this->config->item('email_conf');
        $this->load->library('email', $conf);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('mail address', 'your name');
        $this->email->subject('Support Application');
        $this->email->attach($filename);
        $this->email->to('email dest');

        $cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($filename);

        $message = '<div><img src="cid:' . $cid . '" alt="photo1"/></div>';
        $message .=  $mailBody  ;

        //array à passer au template email
        $data = array(
            'userName' =>  $this->session->userdata('username'),
            'email' => $this->session->userdata ('email'),
            'message' => $message
        );
        $body = $this->load->view('email/template.php', $data, TRUE);
        $this->email->message($body);
        $this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );
        $result = $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

I created a template as a view in a new view folder  views/email/template.php

```
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Template contact / XXX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <FONT face="Verdana" size = "4" ><?php echo $message; ?></FONT>
            <FONT face="Verdana" size = "4" >Message envoyé par : <?php echo   $userName; ?></FONT>
            <FONT face="Verdana" size = "4" >test mail : <?php echo $email; ?></FONT>
        </p> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: it's not helping

Comment: can it be a server issue?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was addressed in an update.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5300

So you should upgrade CI's `/system` to the newest version and your problems should go away.

You could also probably silence depreciated warnings in the switch statement on top of the `index.php` page but that's more of a bandaid rather than a fix.